# How can I create a backward compatible Android paging app widget?

Tags: java, android, widget, android-appwidget

I'm having trouble trying to find any tutorials on how to make a paging app widget like the ones found in Facebook, Twitter and FriendCaster.

I could use the new Android 3.0+ tools with an adapter, however that would be difficult to test as I don't have any devices capable and my computer isn't either.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This can be done by giving your appwidget a state, which defines the page it currently shows. And assign broadcast to the buttons to change state.

1. Send broadcast when buttons are clicked using [PendingIntent](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/PendingIntent.html).
2. Have a [receiver](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/BroadcastReceiver.html) listen to broadcast and keep track of state (page)
3. Update the appwidget depending on the current state

Here is some incomplete code example:

```
RemoteViews remoteViews = new RemoteViews(mContext.getPackageName(), R.layout.widget_weather);

// update appwidget remoteviews depending on state (ie which page to show)
remoteViews = populateViews(remoteViews, mState);

// set next button
Intent intent = new Intent(MYBROADCAST_NEXT);
PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, requestCode, intent, flags);
remoteViews.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.appwidget_btn_next, pendingIntent);

// set prev button
intent = new Intent(MYBROADCAST_PREV);
pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, requestCode, intent, flags);
remoteView.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.appwidget_btn_prev, pendingIntent);

// update the AppWidget ...
```

Hope this helps to achieve what you want.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the compatibility package, it is backwards compatible. The minimum API level is 4, which is Android 1.6

http://developer.android.com/sdk/compatibility-library.html

Use ViewPager, there's plenty of examples for it.
http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2011/08/horizontal-view-swiping-with-viewpager.html

Comment: Can I use it in an App Widget (sorry, I forgot that word, i'll add to the question now)

Comment: I may have completely misread, my answer doesn't hold much weight if you're meaning like home screen widgets...